Javascript using event listener to put value in an input box


const one = document.getElementById("one");
// const input = document.getElementById("input");
one.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // document.forms[0].input.value = '1';

  document.getElementById("input").value = 1;
});
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
}

#clear {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    <input id="input" name="input">
  </form>
  <main>
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div id="clear">CLEAR</div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>



I tried creating buttons using css grid and javascript to put a value to an input box but it doesn't work. I tried this:
document.getElementById("one").value = 1; 

I also tried
document.forms[0].input.value = 1

This is like a calculator problem. You input numbers to an input box by clicking on the number buttons.

It works for me in the above snippet.

Do you want it to keep adding to the input box? So if you click 1 then 2, it puts 12 into the input? Then use += instead of =.

@Barmer The issue seems to be run the script in head element ,try to run the script after the body.

I moved the script to the body and it works now. Thank you guys!

@anonymous because you're simply accessing the element that was not exist in dom and that was due to script runs before the dom get fully loaded. This was similar accessing a variable before the declaration (in programming general).I'm not mentioned javascript here because it has a feature called hoisting .

@anonymous actually it was a nice question.which tells the importance about why scripts need to be loaded after body and styles are need to be loaded before body?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <style>
        main {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px;
            grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        }

        #clear {
            grid-column: 2 / 4;
            grid-row: 4 / 5;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        div {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            background-color: lightgreen;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <input id="input" name="input">
    </form>
    <main>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="1">1</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="2">2</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="3">3</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="4">4</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="5">5</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="6">6</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="7">7</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="8">8</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="9">9</div>
        <div class="num-button" data-value="0">0</div>
        <div id="clear">CLEAR</div>
    </main>
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('.num-button').forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const input = document.getElementById('input');
                input.value += this.dataset.value;
            });
        });

        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('input').value = '';
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>


Thank you for your contribution. However, your answer would be a lot more useful if you added an explanation of what you changed and how it solves the problem.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>here the title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <input id="input" name="input">
      </form>
      <main >
        <div class="item" data-value="1">1</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="2">2</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="3">3</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="4">4</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="5">5</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="6">6</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="7">7</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="8">8</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="9">9</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="0">0</div>
        <div id="clear">CLEAR</div>
      </main>

      <script>
        let allItem=document.querySelectorAll('.item');
        for (let i = 0; i < allItem.length; i++) {
            allItem[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
                document.getElementById('input').value=allItem[i].getAttribute('data-value');
            })
            
        }
        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click',()=>{
            document.getElementById('input').value=''

        })
      </script>
</body>
</html>a


Yeah you're right I'm literally tried to explain this

no problem, this example for prove your explanation

If you create variables for each button and assign event listeners to each of them you end up with a lot of code.
Here I moved the buttons (now <button> elements) onto the form to do everything in the context of the form. And then assign the event listener to the form (event delegation).
I use the data-* attribute to give each button a "value". It can be accessed using the dataset property.


const form = document.forms.form1;

form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON'){
    let output = e.target.form.output;
    if(e.target.dataset.value == 'clear'){
      output.value = '';
    }else{
      output.value = output.value + e.target.dataset.value;
    }
  }
});
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
}

button[data-value="clear"] {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
<form name="form1">
  <input name="output">
  <main>
    <button type="button" data-value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" data-value="clear">CLEAR</button>
  </main>
</form>



